# How to check if textfield is empty?

Tags: javafx, textfield

for my JavaFx application I want to check if the TextFields are empty, and if so, alert the user.
These are the TextFields:

```
VBox fields = new VBox();  
Text usernametext = new Text("User name");
TextField user_name = new TextField();
Text firstnametext = new Text("First name");
TextField first_name = new TextField();
Text lastnametext = new Text("Last name");
TextField last_name = new TextField();
Text ibantext = new Text("IBAN");
TextField iban = new TextField();
Text passwordtext = new Text("Password");
TextField password = new TextField();
Text confirmpasstext = new Text("Confirm password");
TextField confirmpass = new TextField();
Button createBtn = new Button("Create account");
```

for now i just wanted to test the validation on one textfield. this is my validation function that is linked to the createBtn:

```
public void validation(){                

    if(user_name.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
        Alert fail= new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        fail.setHeaderText("failure");
        fail.setContentText("you havent typed something");
        fail.showAndWait();
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText("Succes");
        alert.setContentText("Account succesfully created!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

But I get this error message as i press the 'Create Account' button:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at opdracht1.Opdracht1.validation(Opdracht1.java:36)
    at opdracht1.Opdracht1$2$1.handle(Opdracht1.java:103)
    at opdracht1.Opdracht1$2$1.handle(Opdracht1.java:98)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please say which line 36 of  `Opdracht1.java` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  if(user_name.getText().trim().isEmpty()){

Comment: Then it is expected that the user_name is null. Check your code at where you may set it to null, or you may have multiple variables with the same name.

Comment: a way to do this with regex  (!inputField.getText().matches(" {" +inputField.getText().length() + "}");) just as an extra info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, check if `user_name` is not **null**. If it is not, you are setting a **null** text value to the JavaFX component somewhere in your code.

> `if(user_name.getText().trim().isEmpty()){`

In any case, applying the `trim()` to a **null** value is what causes your exception. You should not need this (see **Uluk Biy**'s comment to this answer), but considering you created a `user_name` TextField, you must check first if the `getText()` method is not **null**.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (user_name.getText() == null || user_name.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
     // your code here
}
```

Comment: The `user_name.getText()` cannot be null because the default constructor of the `TextField` sets the initial text to "" (empty string).

Comment: Absolutely right. However he must set a null value somewhere in the program; it's the only way to get a null pointer in the mentioned line.

Comment: "" is set to text if the argument passed for setText() is null. so getText() ensured not to return null anyway. NPE occurs if user_name is also null for the given line.

Comment: `user_name.setText(null); Assert.assertNotNull(user_name.getText());` Check this. It launches an _AssertionFailedError_, meaning the text returned by the method is null. I'm editing the answer, adding the possibility that user_name may also be null.

Comment: You are right. It seems there is a flag to indicate the text nullness. But the actual value of text property sets to "".

Comment: does the second condition there also pick up user_name.getText().isEmpty() ? Beacuse thats whats in the the textfield when nothing has been typed in it.

Comment: Thanks, brother Alexander!

Answer (score 2):

you can use Button disableProperty to bind with TextField. when the textfield is empty, then the button will be disabled, else it will be enabled.

use code mentioned below

```
createBtn.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () -> 
        user_name.getText().trim().isEmpty(), user_name.textProperty()
    )
    // If you want to check more text field, use it as by removing comments
    //.or(  Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    //         first_name.getText.trim().isEmpty(), first_name.textProperty()
    //     )
    //  )

);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is how I did it and it works.

If in the event none of the above works, try the following:

Create a string variable, let's say String username;
Next, try the following:

```
if(username.trim().isEmpty())
```

The original suggestion didn't work for me but creating the string did, so if the above suggestions did not work for you, give this a shot.

Comment: I guess you mean ```if(username.getText().trim().isEmpty()) ```

Answer (score 1):

This can be checked simply by

```
if(textField.getText().trim().equals(""))
{
system.out.println("textField is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

textField.getText().trim().equals("")

Above statement worked like a charm for me.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can test this code replace the Name of my champs with the name of your TextFeild

```
if ((nom_pt.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0) ||
    (prenom_pt.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0) ||
    (cin_pt.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0) ||
    (gsm_pt.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0)) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "champs vide");

} else {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enregistrement a été  ajouter");  }
```

Comment: This question about `JavaFx` and not `Java Swing`